# Cannot save a new row in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, kendo-grid

I have a problem with saving a new row to my kendo grid.
When id is sent to the server it is 0. But when I try to change it on the server it is still 0.

How can I fix this? I will be glad to any help with this issue.

**My Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Book List";
}

@{
    var defaultAuthor = ViewData["defaultAuthor"]
        as List<Number2.Models.AuthorViewModel>;
    var temp = defaultAuthor.FirstOrDefault().AuthorName as string;
}

<script type="text/kendo" id="authorsTemplate">
    <ul>
        #if(data.Authors == null)
        { #
        data.Authors = @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["defaultAuthor"]))
        # } #
        #if(data.Authors != null)
        { #
        # for(var i = 0; i < Authors.length; i++){ #
        <li>#: Authors[i].AuthorName #</li>
        # } #
        # } #            
    </ul>
</script>

<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
    function authorsEditor(container, options) {
        $('<input name="Authors">').appendTo(container)
            .kendoMultiSelect({
                dataValueField: "AuthorId",
                dataTextField: "AuthorName",
                dataSource: @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["authors"]))    
            });
    }

    //added var grid
    var grid =  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        pageable: true,           
        toolbar: ["create"],
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 3,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Read", "Grid")",
                    type: "POST"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Update", "Grid")",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    //complete: function (e) {
                    //    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    //},
                    type: "POST"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Create", "Grid")",
                    contentType: "application/json",//hz nado li
                    type: "POST"
                },
                 destroy: {
                    url: "@Url.Action("Destroy", "Grid")",
                    contentType: "application/json",//hz nado li
                    type: "POST"
                },
                parameterMap: function(options) {
                    return kendo.stringify(options);
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "BookId",
                    fields: {
                        AuthorName: { type: "string" }    
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        editable: "inline",
        columns: [
            { field: "BookName", width: 90, title: "Book Name" },
            "Pages",
            //    { editor: GenreEditor, field: "Genre" },IEnumerable<Number2.Models.AuthorViewModel>
            "Genre",
            "Publisher",
            {
                editor: authorsEditor,
                field: "Authors",
                template: $("#authorsTemplate").html(),
                @*defaultValue: @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["defaultAuthor"]))*@
            },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"] }
        ]
    });

    //$(".k-grid-my-create", grid.element).on("click", function (e) {
    //    var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
    //    var total = dataSource.data();
    //    dataSource.insert(total, {});
    //    dataSource.page(dataSource.totalPages());
    //    grid.editRow(grid.tbody.children().last());
    //});
</script>
```

**GridController**

I tried to change the value in the create method, but it is not working.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(BookViewModel book)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.UpdateBook(book);
    }

    return Json(new[] { book }.ToDataSourceResult(new DataSourceRequest(), ModelState));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BookViewModel book)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        book.BookId = repository.CreateBook(book);
    }

    return Json(new[] { book }.ToDataSourceResult(new DataSourceRequest(), ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Book Model**

```
namespace Number2.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {

        }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public string BookName { get; set; }

        public int Pages { get; set; }

        public string Publisher { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Author model**

```
namespace Number2.Models
{
    public class Author
    {
        public Author()
        {

        }
        [Required]
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Author Name")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Author Name must be 100 characters or less"), MinLength(5)]
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**BookViewModel**

```
namespace Number2.Models
{
    public class BookViewModel
    {
        public BookViewModel()
        {
            Authors = new List<AuthorViewModel>();
        }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Book Name")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Book Name must be 100 characters or less"), MinLength(5)]
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }

        public string Publisher { get; set; }

        [Range(0, maximum: 10)]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [UIHint("AuthorsEditor")]
        public virtual List<AuthorViewModel> Authors { get; set; }
        public void CopyToBook(Book book)
        {
            book.BookId = BookId;
            book.BookName = BookName;
            book.Pages = Pages;
            book.Genre = Genre;
            book.Publisher = Publisher;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your Book model defined? Is BookId an identity field or do you assign it yourself?

Comment: Question updated

Comment: OK, so BookId would be an identity column (unless you have fluent code that changes the default behavior). When you add it, the id should be set. What does repository.CreateBook(book) do?